# Custom Summernote Button to create links with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, summernote

So I'm thoroughly confused as how to make a custom SummerNote button which will allow me to either add classes to an already inserted HTML element (i.e. links) or even wrap selected text in something like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"> **selected text** </button>
```

From the [Summernote Deep Dive](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-button) it shows how to create a custom button that inserts static text and I understand how to implement it. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make it dynamic for whatever text is selected. I've tried replacing the `'text'` part of the example after `context.invoke` call but it doesn't convert the text to html, it just prints it.

The need is for creating links as buttons. Ideally I'd wish to access the `Insert Link` dialog already built into SummerNote to make buttons that will insert links with predefined classes but I'm not sure how complicated that would be.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
var bsButton = function (context) {
var ui = $.summernote.ui;

// create button
var button = ui.button({
    contents: 'Btn',
    tooltip: 'Create Button',
    click: function () {
        // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
        context.invoke('editor.insertText', '<button class="btn btn-primary"></button>');
    }
});

return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
}
```

I've reviewed a ton of different posts but I haven't gotten much further than the example for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was doing more research I stumbled upon [Summernote's 'Awesome Summernote' GitHub page](https://github.com/summernote/awesome-summernote) which led me to a plugin, [summernote-addclass](https://github.com/creativeprogramming/summernote-addclass). While this doesn't necessarily answer the heart of the question (i.e. achieving this same thing without a plugin) but it does exactly what I need to do. Maybe this will help someone else in the future. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

By using **jQuery** in summernote callback method **onInit** I have added custom class for custom button

Here is my custom button code:

```
var AddPage = function(context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-plus"/> Add Page',
        tooltip: "Set a New Page",
        class: "btn-primary",
        click: function() {
          addPage();
        }
    });
    return button.render();
};
```

And i use callback methods to add custom class **btn-primary**  to the button

```
$("#editor").summernote({
      airMode: false,
      dialogsInBody: false,
      toolbar: [["mybutton", ["customButton"]],
      buttons: {
        customButton: AddPage
      },
      callbacks: {
        onInit: function(e) {
          var o = e.toolbar[0];
          jQuery(o)
            .find("button:first")
            .addClass("btn-primary");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

I think this may be helpful for anyone, even if this is not gud answer.